# 419 page expired on register form

Tags: laravel

I have two divs with form login and register.login is working but register is giving me the error page expired I have even added @csrf but it still not working but it's working on the login form

```html
<form action="{{route('register')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="textbox">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
        <input type="name" placeholder="Username" name="name" class="inputs">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="textbox">
        <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="inputs" autocomplete="new-password">
    </div>

    <div class="textbox">
        <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="password_confirmation" value="" class="inputs">
    </div>
    <div id="terms"><input type="checkbox"> I have read and agreed to the <a href="">terms and conditions</a></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit-buttons">
</form>
```

Comment: You're including the csrf token twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove one of this lines:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

or

```
@csrf
```